# JavaScript Variables in succession

Tags: javascript

if this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LinkOnClick2(box2) {
    $('#load').load('ajaxdeletelistenchat.php?q=<?php echo $identify; ?>&wpm2=' + box2);
}
</script>
```

I am trying to make it like this.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function LinkOnClick2(box2) {
    var commentlimit = document.getElementById('commentlimit').value;
    $('#load').load('ajaxdeletelistenchat.php?q=<?php echo $identify; ?>&wpm2=' + box2  & commentlimit=' + commentlimit);
```

But my variables are not being passed correctly.  Could anyone please help me and tell me what is wrong with the way that I have my variables setup?
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing ' before &commentlimit and you have space between & and commentlimit, try with this:

```
$('#load').load('ajaxdeletelistenchat.php?q=<?php echo $identify; ?>&wpm2=' + box2  + '&commentlimit=' + commentlimit);
```